# dust.js - render the first element of an array

Tags: javascript, json, dust.js

I have a .json data object that looks like this:

```
{ images: [ { photo: image.jpg } {something : else} ] }
```

I want to get access in my dust templating to the `image.jpg` item. Is there a straightforward way to select only the first dictionary in that array without looping through? I'd prefer to avoid a loop in my template because it will render a section that is expecting `style="background-image: url({photo});"` multiple times.

Answer (score 8):

Use {images[0]} to get just the first element.